# How to return a value from a callback function

Tags: java, android

I want to return a String from a callback

My class which fetch date from server in a thread and i want this value in main thread as a String. I am beginner in Java.

```
public class InternetDate {

private final Activity activity;
private String finalDate = "";

public InternetDate(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}


public void setDateAndTimeFormat(String dateAndTimeFormat) {
    mDateAndTimeFormat = dateAndTimeFormat;
}

public void getCurrentDate(OnGetDate onGetDate) {
    new BackgroundTask(activity) {
        @Override
        public void doInBackground() {
            try {
                finalDate = getCurrentDateFromInternet();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute() {
            try {
                JSONObject jb = new JSONObject(finalDate);
                String name = jb.getString("UnixTimeStamp");
                onGetDate.onSuccess(name);
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
               
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}


private String getCurrentDateFromInternet() throws Exception {
    String date_api = example.com/api;
    URL url = new URL(date_api);
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        return in.readLine();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

public interface OnGetDate {
    void onSuccess(String date);
}
```

I want this as a String. Please help me to archive this String in MainThread

```
private String getDate(){
    String currentDate = "";
    InternetDate internetDate = new InternetDate(this);
    internetDate.getCurrentDate(new InternetDate.OnGetDate() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String date) {
            currentDate = date; // Null return
        }
    });
    return currentDate;
}
```

Comment: What does `getCurrentDate` do? Is it blocking or non-blocking?

Comment: But what if your callback isn't called before the method returns? What do you want to happen then?

Comment: I update my question. Please Check

Comment: `return currentDate;` retuns `null` because it returns before your `onSuccess` method is executed. You could put the code that does something with the date inside the `onSuccess` method. Or use a MutableLiveData object to notify an observer. I can give you an example if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You might wait for the response using a semaphore, but this kind of code is blocking by nature and leads to apps with a poor user experience, because the ui thread is blocked during the whole process

```
//import java.util.concurrent.*;
//[...]
private String getDate() throws TimeoutException {

    final String[] result = new String[]{null};
    final Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);

    new InternetDate(this).getCurrentDate(new InternetDate.OnGetDate() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String date) {
            result[0] = date; // Null return
            sem.release();
        }
    });

    try {
        if (sem.tryAcquire(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            return result[0];
        } else {
            throw new TimeoutException("no response after 10 seconds");
        }
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) :

```java
private String getDate() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    // This line is non-blocking:
    Future<String> future = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
            .submit(() -> new InternetDate().getCurrentDateFromInternet());
    // The invocation of 'get' is blocking:
    return future.get();
}
```

I assume `getCurrentDateFromInternet` returns the date in the format you want.

Comment: Can't create handler inside thread Thread

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved using a MutableLiveData object **without** blocking the UI thread.

Let's start assuming you have a main class named `MainThread` where your `getDate` method lives.

In this class first create the following `MutableLiveData` object:

```
  private MutableLiveData<String> date = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

The object above will be updated with the date value as soon as it's available to your program.

Next create/update the method that'll make a call to the `getDate` method (which we'll keep for simplicity's sake):

```
private void exampleDateMethod() {
    // first create an observer; in the observer you put the code that does something with the Date
    date.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged( String date ) {
            // this is where you do something with the date, an example:
            findViewById( R.id.date_view ).setText( date );
        }
    });
    // pass the MutableLiveData to the getDate method so that its value can be updated:
    getDate( date );
}
```

And change the `getDate` method to pass the Date to the MutableLiveData object:

```
private void getDate( MutableLiveData<String> liveDate ){
    internetDate.getCurrentDate(new InternetDate.OnGetDate() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String date) {
            // set the value of  the MutableLiveData object, this will notify the observer and execute the code in its onChanged method
            liveData.setValue( date );
        }
    });
}
```